# FinancialData works in Wolfram Script, not in Notebook

Tags: financialdata

FinancialData has recently stopped working in the Mathematica 13.1 front end on my Windows 11 PC.

I can execute FinancialData["GE"] in wolframscript and it returns the correct answer.

But when I try the same command in a new Notebook I get a strange error message:

```
Missing[UnknownType, Financial]
```

Other installations in Windows 10 or Mac OS work fine.  So I am wondering if its possibly a Windows 11 issue, or simply some kind of corruption in the front end.

To test the latter hypothesis I uninstalled and re-installed MMA.  It still gives the same error message.  So I am leaning towards some kind of incompatibility between MMA and Windows 11.

Any ideas/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's a Windows 11 issue.  Nothing would fix the error until I downgraded to Windows 10.  To be fair, I don't think WR suggests full compatibility with Windows 11, so the mistake is mine.  I've turned off updates to stop Windows nagging.